# Spring "SchedulerFactoryBean" overrides the "jobstore" properties value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

If you are using Spring's SchedulerFactoryBean, it overrides the configured value from the properties file.
So if you tried to use JobStoreTx it is always overridden by the LocalDataSourceJobStore from spring

Code snippet below shows the part from the SchedulerFactoryBean. I have overcome it by using a customizer.

```
        if (this.dataSource != null) {
            mergedProps.setProperty(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_JOB_STORE_CLASS, LocalDataSourceJobStore.class.getName());
        }
```

Comment: Can you please write (maybe as an answer to your own "question", I've done it several times) the code with which you got around this problem? I'm using a customizer too but I can't see how I'm supposed to make the bean use the JobStore class I want. I know it's late but...

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved this issue by providing the DataSource via a `@Bean` annotated with `@QuartzDataSource`. If the DataSource isn't "manually" set on the factory bean, Quartz will correctly use your configured JobStore class.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I think ur comment makes much sense but I faced another problem as the Datasource in my case is provided to my app, I have no way to override it.

So a `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer` solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@QuartzDataSource` should handle the problem as @nonzaprej mentioned in the comments

Here is also how I have overridden the value using a customizer

```
@Component
public class SchedulerFactoryCustomizer implements SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer {
```

using the customize method

```
    @Override
    public void customize(SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean) {
        schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
```